# How to add hyphen when days of week are concurrent

Tags: javascript

Example1 :

```
daysofweek=['MON','TUE','WED','THU','FRI','SUN'] ;
```

output should be :

```
MON-FRI,SUN
```

Example2 :

```
daysofweek=['MON',TUE'];
```

output should be :

```
MON,TUE
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: please try to solve the problem first then asking for the part which you stuck with your code

Comment: I think, by definition, days of the week can't be concurrent. Contiguous perhaps.

Comment: why should the output be `MON-FRI,SUN` ?

Comment: ^  and also why wouldn't ['MON','TUE'] become MON-TUE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var oneDArray = function(weekArray){

  var week = []; 
  for(var  i=0; i< weekArray.length;i++){
        var conDays = weekArray[i];
        if((sorter[conDays[1]] - sorter[conDays[0]]) === 0 ){
            week[i] = conDays[0];
        }
        else if((sorter[conDays[1]] - sorter[conDays[0]]) === 1 ){
            week[i] = conDays;
        }else{
            week[i] = conDays.join("-");
        } 
  }
  return week.join();
};

var convertToWeekRanges = function (week) {
       var weekRanges = [] 
       weekRanges[0] = [week[0], week[0]];
       var  lastIndex = 0;

    for (var i = 1; i < week.length; i++) {

        if ((sorter[week[i]] - sorter[weekRanges[lastIndex][1]]) === 1) {
            weekRanges[lastIndex][1] = week[i];
        } else {
            weekRanges[++lastIndex] = [week[i], week[i]];
        }
    }
    return weekRanges;
};

console.log(oneDArray(convertToWeekRanges(['MON','TUE'] )));

console.log(oneDArray(convertToWeekRanges(['MON','TUE','WED','THU','SAT','SUN'])));

console.log(oneDArray(convertToWeekRanges(['MON','TUE','WED','THU','FRI','SUN'])));
```

Comment: my question is how to add hyphen when iterate days of week are concurrent.MON-FRI,SUN.  if there is no concurrent weeks and that will displayed as comma separated values.

Comment: var daysofweek=['MON','TUE'];   output is now MON-TUE  : but expected is MON,TUE

Comment: As you see MON-TUE is consecutive.  thats why you are getting this output.

Comment: consuective should  be consider more than 2 length

Comment: Update function -> var oneDArray = function(weekArray){
  var week = []; 
  for(var  i=0; i< weekArray.length;i++){
        var conDays = weekArray[i];

        console.log(sorter[conDays[1]] - sorter[conDays[0]]);

        if(conDays.length == 1 ||  (sorter[conDays[1]] - sorter[conDays[0]]) === 1 ){
            week[i] = conDays;
        }else{
            week[i] = conDays.join("-");
        }
  }
  return week.join();
};

Comment: Glad to help @harry Please mark this as accepted solution. So that other also get benefitted.

Comment: var daysofweek=['MON','TUE','WED','THU','SAT','SUN'] ; output is now MON-THU,SUN :  But expected is MON-THU,SAT,SUN

Comment: @harry  Code has been updated.  Glad to help. Please check its working or not?

Comment: @harry hopefully its working?

Comment: working fine as expected.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can take a reference of all days in week to compare which day is missing and use `split` and `map` on missing day like below

```js
let daysofweek1 = ['MON','TUE','WED', 'THU','FRI','SUN'] ;

let daysofweek2 = ['MON','WED','THU','FRI','SUN'] ;

let daysofweek3 = ['TUE','WED']; 

let allWeeks = ['MON','TUE','WED','THU','FRI','SAT', 'SUN']

function getCombinedDays(arr) {
  return allWeeks.map(d => arr.some(v => v == d) ? d : '-')
                 .join('')
                 .split('-')
                 .flatMap(d => d.length > 3 ? (d.length == 6 ? [d.slice(0,3), d.slice(-3)] : d.slice(0,3) + '-' + d.slice(-3)) : d)
                 .filter(d => d)
}

console.log(getCombinedDays(daysofweek1))

console.log(getCombinedDays(daysofweek2))

console.log(getCombinedDays(daysofweek3))
```